# ERROR: cannot verify www.opscode.com's certificate

Tags: chef, knife

I am using OSS Chef 11.0.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , while running Knife ec2 create command I am getting below error

Bootstrapping Chef on ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

```
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com --2014-02-20 12:26:15--  https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com Resolving www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)... 184.106.28.90
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com Connecting to www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)|184.106.28.90|:443... connected.
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ERROR: cannot verify www.opscode.com's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Secure Server CA’:
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com   Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com To connect to www.opscode.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
  ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com bash: line 88: chef-client: command not found
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I got the answer for this in chef-full.erb file we need to disable ssl check

```
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484-devel/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-ful

 install_sh="https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh"
```

change this to

```
 install_sh="http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh"
```

Also

```
 wget --no-check-certificate
```

use --no-check-certificate

Comment: Down-voting this because it's a very, *very* bad practice to disable SSL here. This is a shell script run as root, and disabling SSL opens the connection to a MiTM attack. You are giving the attacker root access to your server.